# How to call RestFul WCF POST service using POSTMAN or any client tool application?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soapui, restful-url

okay lets say I want to use POSTMAN or any other Rest service client tool to call my code, how should can I do it? one of my parameters "data" is huge and I **dont** want include the "data" or payload in URL, I want to call it from the body?

here is the actual code

```
  [OperationContract(Name = "createNewSurvey")]
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "post/createNewSurvey")]
  string CreateNewSurvey(string id, string Data);  


 public string CreateNewSurvey(string id, [FromBody]string Data)
  {
      //do somethoinf
      return data;
  }
```

any help would be appreciated it

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In Postman you have to write this string http://localhost/Sample/Service1.svc/createNewSurvey in the box "Enter the request URL" and selected POST, add in the header these two keys:

- Content-Type:application/json
- Host:localhost

and in the body select "raw" radio button and write:

- {"id":"5","Data":"sample data to be sent to server"}

[see the image like example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5sUI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Install a tool called [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and then use the below raw request.

```
URL:http://localhost/Sample/Service1.svc/post/createNewSurvey
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost

{"id":"5","Data":"sample data to be sent to server"}
```

Comment: I think Postman is more suitable for the OP context... fiddler is for more complex inspection